# Meaning of $\vec{r}^n$ and proof for $\nabla(\vec{r}^n)=nr^{n-2}\vec r$

Tags: vectors

I have to prove $\nabla(\vec{r}^n)=nr^{n-2}\vec r$, where $\vec{r}=x\hat i+y\hat j+z\hat k$.

But how can I define the powers of vector? $r^2$ is $r.r$. Is $r^3=(r.r)r$? But then how will I define the gradient of $r^3$ since its a vector?

Comment: I think, as much as I have seen in many textbooks, that the problem is about $\nabla(r^n)$ and not about $\nabla(\vec{r}^n)$. The first makes clear sense, but the second notation has ambiguity.

Comment: Most (physics) books put the vector symbol on top of the gradient so I suppose it's a typing mistake: i.e. $\vec {\nabla} r^n$ and not $\nabla(\vec{r}^n)$.

Comment: @Liebe I never saw the vector symbol on top of the gradient in any Physics book. Maybe, it is quite old literature.

Comment: @FelixMarin, I don't have access to my books now but for example see https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YW-bUVIOpB0 . The vector symbol on top of the gradient doesn't occurs in some texts because authors type it "bold" for an alternative to display a vector .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[8px,border:1px groove navy]{{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\partiald{r^{n}}{x} & =
nr^{n - 1}\,\partiald{r}{x} =
{1 \over 2}\,nr^{n - 2}\,\partiald{r^{2}}{x} =
{1 \over 2}\,nr^{n - 2}\,\partiald{\pars{x^{2} + y^{2} + z^{2}}}{x} =
{1 \over 2}\,nr^{n - 2}\,\pars{2x} = nr^{n - 2}\,x
\end{align}
Similarly for $\ds{y\ \mbox{and}\ z}$ 'components'. So,
$\bbox[#ffe,10px,border:1px dashed navy]{\,%
\ds{\nabla r^{n} = nr^{n - 2}\ \vec{r}}}\,$.

Answer (score 1):

If $f$ is an scalar then $$\nabla f = \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial r} \hat{r} + \dfrac{1}{r} \ \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial \theta} \hat{\theta} + \dfrac{1}{r \sin \theta} \ \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial \phi} \hat{\phi} $$ so for the case of $f=f(r)$ we have $\nabla f(r) = \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial r} \dfrac{\vec r}{r} = \dfrac{\partial r^n}{\partial r} \dfrac{\vec r}{r} = nr^{n-2}\vec r$.

PS For $\vec f$ being a vector we may define the "Tensor derivative". See e.g.  [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_derivative_(continuum_mechanics)).

Answer (score 1):

The detailed proof is as follows :
$$\vec{r}=x\hat i+ y\hat j + z\hat k$$
$$|\vec r|^n=r^n=\sqrt[n]{x^2+y^2+z^2}$$
$$\nabla =\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\hat i+\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\hat j +\frac{\partial}{\partial z}\hat k $$

$$\nabla r^n =\frac{\partial r^n}{\partial x}\hat i+\frac{\partial r^n}{\partial y}\hat j +\frac{\partial r^n}{\partial z}\hat k $$

$$\frac{\partial r^n}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial (x^2+y^2+z^2)^{n/2}}{\partial x}= \frac{n}{2}(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{\frac{n}{2}-1}\frac{\partial}{\partial x} (x^2+y^2+z^2)$$

$$= \frac{n}{2}(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{\frac{n}{2}-1}2x$$

$$= n(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{\frac{n}{2}-1}x$$
$||y$

$$\frac{\partial r^n}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial (x^2+y^2+z^2)^{n/2}}{\partial y}= n(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{\frac{n}{2}-1}y$$

and $$\frac{\partial r^n}{\partial z}=\frac{\partial (x^2+y^2+z^2)^{n/2}}{\partial z}= n(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{\frac{n}{2}-1}z$$
Finally,
$$\nabla r^n=n(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{n/2-1}(x\hat i+ y\hat j + z\hat k)$$

$$\nabla r^n=n(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{n/2-1}\vec r$$

$$\nabla r^n=n(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{\frac{n-2}{2}}\vec r$$

$$\nabla r^n=nr^{n-2}\vec r$$